# JavaFX: how to disable drag and drop and pasting from external sources on WebView?

Tags: java, webview, drag-and-drop, javafx-2, copy-paste

I am working on a chat application where I am using a  `webView`  to show the conversation between sender and receiver and another  `webView` to write the message which will contain text and emoticons **(the reason for using webView is that it is capable to show emoticons along text using html)**, the 2nd `webView` is editable by setting its  `contenteditable`  property to  `true`  in html, now the problem is that when I drag and drop text or copy text from somewhere which contains formatting, links and images it will be shown with all the formatting that is why I want to disable dragAndDrop and pasting text from external sources such as browsers, if the text contains links then by clicking that link it will direct you to that page and the `webView` will become a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky (i think). One way to do it is by providing your own EventDispatcher instance and intercept the actions you want to prevent, e.g. intercepting the DragEvent to prevent drops and the key events for the paste action. The downsides to this approach are, of course:

1) You'd have to code platform specific for the paste shortcut (CTRL+V vs. META+V)

2) If you want to disable pasting via the context menu this way, you'd have to prevent it from appearing at all. However I think in your case that would be intended.

So, pending a better a better solution I'd go with the dispatcher. Determine which events you want to be processed and forward those to the dispatcher chain. Consume the events you want to prevent.